# File Streaming using Java similar to node.js

Tags: java, node.js

I was going over a nodejs tutorial which mentioned that Node.JS does not keep the file in memory when writes files to a disk and it flushes chunks of file to disk as and when it receives it. Is Java capable of handling file in a similar fashion or does it keep the entire file in memory before flushing to disk? In the past , I have faced out of memory exception when I tried to upload files using servlets.

Comment: Streaming goes way beyond Java or NodeJS. Back in the days memory was a lot more precious, so you wouldn't even imagine the common mistake new programmers do, i.e. keeping everything in memory.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes, In java you can use streaming APIs that can help you do it. 
try the following guide to understand it better :
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html

Example :
Fileupload using Servlet:

```
// Check that we have a file upload request
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
```

ow we are ready to parse the request into its constituent items. Here's how we do it:

```
// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
// Parse the request
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
      FileItemStream item = iter.next();
     String name = item.getFieldName();
     InputStream stream = item.openStream();
     if (item.isFormField()) {
               System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value " + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
     } else {
              System.out.println("File field " + name + " with file name " + item.getName() + " detected.");
              // Process the input stream
              ...
     }
}
```

And at last you can write the input stream in a file using the follwing approach :

```
FileOutputStream fout= new FileOutputStream ( yourPathtowriteto );
BufferedOutputStream bout= new BufferedOutputStream (fout);
BufferedInputStream bin= new BufferedInputStream(stream);


int byte;
while ((byte=bin.read()) != -1)
{
     bout.write(byte_);
}
bout.close();
bin.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much